# Passing parameters vs public variables when calling method in dll (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, parameters, global-variables

I am moving some code from my main project into a dll in order to make my application more dynamic (the dll can be exchanged for another one, sort of a plugin). Several subroutines in my main project have been bundled into one in the dll, and different pieces of code are run depending on a variable passed from the main project. This is in turn selected from a database which is updated by the dll as it is loaded, making it possible to add completely new functionality without having to install a new version of the app.

Now, except for arguments being passed from the calling code to the subroutine in the dll, the code in that sub also uses values of some publicly declared variables that keep track of things like the source path of input data, whether the user has made changes to some objects etc. Before moving the code, these were declared in a module of my main project. The values are now, however, needed by the sub in my dll.

I could pass all those variable values as arguments to the sub in the dll even though most of them are not used every time the call is made (since I only use one sub for everything that the dll does). This seems like the simplest solution. However, I know that having methods with like 10+ parameters is considered bad practice.  Or I could move the public variables to an interface dll (which already exists), values of which both my main project and my dll can access and update the values there.

Which is best (or least bad) in terms of performance? Could one of the choices have unexpected consequences?

Comment: This gives me the impression that your method are shared. You should instead pass these configuration parameter to the constructor of the object and keep those value as class variable. Then, your method can easily get the values from the class.

Comment: Obvious when someone tells you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This gives me the impression that your methods might be shared. You should instead pass these configuration parameter to the constructor of the object and keep those value as class variable. Then, your method can easily get the values from the class.

```
Class SomeClass

    Public Sub New(ByVal someParameter As String)
        Me.SomeParameter = someParameter
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property SomeParameter As String

    Public Sub SomeMethod()
        ' Can use Me.SomeParameter here
    End Sub

End Class
```